# Apply discount to shipping cost in magento

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I want to apply discount on shipping rate. For example if cart subtotal is greater than $125 then there will a discount of $17 on the shipping cost. I have created shipping cart rule in admin but the rule gets applied on the cart subtotal, not on the shipping cost. I have selected the options "apply to shipping amount" as yes and "Stop Further Rules Processing" as no.

Do anybody have idea about how I can do this. Any help will really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @pady have you found answer to that?..i need this too

Comment: You get solution at below link

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52886/how-can-i-give-discount-on-shipping-costs

Comment: **You get solution at below link**

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52886/how-can-i-give-discount-on-shipping-costs

Answer (score 0):

You can try below extension:

http://wiki.webshopapps.com/extensions/shipping-discount/configuration

However I could not find its download url

Answer (score -2):

You can  go to Magento Admin panel 
 First Step : Promitions

Second Step : Shopping Cart Price Rule

Then go to Conditions in Left Side bar

Apply a Conditions on that What ever You want

For example You want a dicount on Subtotal then Apply

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
Subtotal  is  125
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have already tried it. But it applies on the cart subtotal amount. I want it to be applied on shipping cost. If subtotal is more than $125 then there will be a discount on shipping cost, not on the cart subtotal. Thanks again.